# Looping with Conditions through a xml file using lxml etree

Tags: python, lxml, elementtree

I wonder if it's possible to make conditional statments connected with a tree.findall("...") statement in lxml library?

I have the following xml structure in a file

```
    <sss version="1.2">
    <date>2011-09-23</date>
    <time>12:32:29</time>
    <origin>OPST</origin>
    <user></user>
    <survey>
        <name>Test</name>
        <version>2011-09-02 15:50:10</version>
        <record ident="A">
            <variable ident="10" type="quantity">
                <name>no_v</name>
                <label>Another question</label>
                <position start="23" finish="24"/>
                <values>
                    <range from="0" to="32"/>
                </values>
            </variable>
            <variable ident="11" type="quantity">
                <name>v_683</name>
                <label>another totally another Question</label>
                <position start="25" finish="26"/>
                <values>
                    <range from="0" to="33"/>
                </values>
            </variable>
            <variable ident="12" type="quantity">
                <name>v_684</name>
                <label>And once more Question</label>
                <position start="27" finish="29"/>
                <values>
                    <range from="0" to="122"/>
                </values>
            </variable>
            <variable ident="20" type="single">
                <name>v_684</name>
                <label>Question with alternatives</label>
                <position start="73" finish="73"/>
                <values>
                    <range from="1" to="6"/>
                    <value code="1">Alternative 1</value>
                    <value code="2">Alternative 2</value>
                    <value code="3">Alternative 3</value>
                    <value code="6">Alternative 4</value>
                </values>
            </variable>
        </record>
    </survey>
</sss>
```

What I want to do now is to get only survey/record/variable/name .text and survey/record/variable/values/value .text if the name starts with "v_"

So far i have the first part

```
from lxml import etree as ET
tree = ET.parse('scheme.xml')
[elem.text for elem in tree.getiterator(tag='name') if elem.text.startswith('v_')]
```

But how can I get the survey/record/variable/values/value .text of the SAME element...and use survey/record/variable/name .text like a filter?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[(elem.text,elem.getparent().xpath('values/value/text()')) 
 for elem in tree.getiterator(tag='name') if elem.text.startswith('v_')]
```

yields

```
[('v_683', []),
 ('v_684', []),
 ('v_684',
  ['Alternative 1', 'Alternative 2', 'Alternative 3', 'Alternative 4'])]
```

`elem` is a `name` element. So to get the the associated values, you can first find its parent (`variable`), then search for the `values` child, and then the `value` subchild elements.

---

An alternative that removes the `getparent` call, but uses a slightly more complicated XPath is:

```
[(elem.text,elem.xpath('following-sibling::values/value/text()')) for elem in tree.getiterator(tag='name')  if elem.text.startswith('v_')]
```

`following-sibling::` tells `xpath` to generate all siblings of `name`.

`following-sibling::values` tells `xpath` to generate all siblings of `name` that are `values` elements.

Comment: holy! That looks quite advanced...Thanx a lot! Anyone has a good link to an introduction into the whole thing?

Comment: @Jurudocs: I learned XPath from [this tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp) but note that that site has garnered [some criticism](http://w3fools.com/). So once you get the basic idea, rely on [the specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) as the definitive resource.

Comment: Thanx that looks like a good introduction to get further with that issue... great help!

Comment: is there something to get the name of the Attributes like #print (elem.getparent().xpath('attribute::values/value'))

Comment: Indeed, you guessed it! Try something like: `xpath('values/value/attribute::code')`